# If $a+b \geq x$ is known to be true does that mean $a+b\geq x-1$ contradicts it?

Tags: logic, proof-verification

So I was proving something and I'm wondering if this line of argument is correct.

Suppose that it is true that given conditions $M,N,O$; $a+b\geq x$. That is given those conditions the minimum value of $a+b$ is $x$.

Now I want to prove using contradiction that an argument $X$ is true. So I assume that $X$ is false. Under the assumption that $X$ is false, I arrive at conditions $M,N,O$. I also have that $a+b\geq x-1$. Which is a contradiction since $a+b\geq x$ given conditions $M,N,O$. Is my argument correct? Did I arrive at a contradiction?

I hope you guys can help. I tried to generalize the problem because it's more with the reasoning that I am concerned about. Thank you!

Comment: Well if I'm not mistaking $x>x-1$ and we have that $a+b>x>x-1$?

Comment: Uhm. Under conditions $M,N,O,$ $a+b$ is at least $x$. But $a+b\geq x-1$ implies that $a+b$ can be $x-1$.

Comment: @chowching We know that $3\ge -1$. Does that really imply $3$ can be $-1$?

Answer (score 0):

No, you haven't provided a contradiction. Suppose that $A = \{1,2,3\}$ and $B=\{3,4,5\}$ and let $a\in A, b\in B.$ Then it is true that $a+b \geq 4.$ Now, let $P$ be the proposition that $a\geq 0,b\geq0$ for any $a\in A, b\in B$. Then $P$ implies $a+b \geq 0.$ This does not contradict $P$, which is reassuring since $P$ is definitely true!

For the contradiction you desire, it would be necessary to demonstrate the existence of a pair $a,b$ with $a+b<x.$ For example, you could try to show there exist $a,b$ with $a+b=x-1.$